# Microcontroller with integrated GSM & GPS support?

Tags: microcontroller, gps, gsm

I am looking for a single chip microcontroller with GSM & GPS solution. Is there any microcontroller chip which is specifically available for GSM & GPS solution? So that it will act like single chip with GPS, GSM (without analog design for GSM) and with programmable controller.

Looking forward for your valuable suggestion. If not, what are the other options I should consider?

Excuse me if isn't a valid post.

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple single chip controller solution that integrates GSM/GPS. There are very complex designs involved. What you probably want/need is something like the [AirPrime](http://www.sierrawireless.com/en/productsandservices/AirPrime_Wireless_Modules/Smart_Modules/Q_Series.aspx)  module.

[image]

It integrates an ARM946 controller and provides interfaces like

- UART
- SPI
- USB
- dozens of GPIOs
- ...

The modules are typically programmed in C/C++ using the [OpenAT Framework](http://www.sierrawireless.com/en/productsandservices/AirPrime_Wireless_Modules/Smart_Modules/Application_Framework.aspx) using the "Developer Studio" which is free.

> Sierra Wireless Open AT® Application Framework is a complete software package for developing embedded M2M applications in standard C/C++. 
>   Designed specifically for M2M: with native support for wireless services (voice call, data call, SMS) and TCP/IP connectivity

Comment: You have mentioned it has Uart,spi,usb. Will it act as master?So that i can interface my gps directly to the Sierra AirPRime

Comment: Yes, in essence the module just encapsulates an ARM controller (which hosts the periphals) and a GSM modem. Check the links in my answer for further details. I haven't used the OpenAT framework myself, so I would have to read up on the details as well.

Comment: SIM868 has GSM/GPS now, and MT2503 is reprogrammable

Answer (score 1):

There are certain kinds of circuits that present some extra legal challenges for the designers. In this case for example, the GSM part has to have an official RF-conformance test done for the particular design/product, and that can be a serious cost factor, unless you plan to produce zillions of this product. If this is not the case, chances are you are better off with using an already built GSM-module that already has a conformance test done.